# How is the order of tables/chains in nftables arranged?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

For example, I have two tables:

```
table inet filter2 {
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
    ct state established,related accept
    iifname $wireif oifname $wirelessif accept
  }
}

table inet filter {
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
    drop
  }
}
```

The `filter` is executed first, so all my forward packets are dropped, which is not what I want. How can I set a table/chain to be executed at last to make it work as the default option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nftables uses underlying netfilter framework which [has 6 hooks points](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks) located at different places in linux kernel network stack.

When one or more rules are added at same hook point netfilter framework priorities the rules by their [priority type](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Chains).

For example in your case while adding chain you can use different priority type for each chain.
Lets say you want to give higher priority to rule defined `forward chain` of

`filter table` than `forward chain` of `filter2 table`

.

> `nft add table ip filter2`
>
> `nft add chain ip filter2 forward {type filter hook forward priority 0 \;}`

Now to give higher priority to `forward chain` of `filter` table assign  priority less than 0.

> `nft add table inet filter`
>
> `nft add chain inet filter '{type filter hook forward priority -1 }'`

Here higher priority value means lower priority and vice-a-versa.

But be careful while using different priority type because it sometime may cause unintended behaviour to packet. For more information read [this](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/firewalls/nftables-second-language-35937)

PS: There is slight [different syntax  for negative priority](https://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1083).

Comment: When the question was posted, the priority had not been implemented (though we can specify them, it simply does not work). Nonetheless I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: And now it has 7 hooks (+ingress)